# Can not show message from the reducer in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to show `message` `'hello brozz..'` from the reducer to a component `render()` method.`ComponentDidMount()` get the `this.props.message` as [please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpNj6.png). And my reducer is like

```
 export const geod = (state ={}, action) => {
      console.log('inside reducer');
        switch(action.type){


            case 'INITIAL_MESSAGE':

              return [
                        ...state, {
                          message:'hello brozz..'
                        }
                      ]
            case 'CLICK_MESSAGE':
                  return [ 
                            ...state, { 
                                            message: ''
                                      }
                          ]
            default:
                    return state;
        }

     };
```

But I can not use `this.props.message` as `<div><div>{this.props.message}</div></div>` inside the render method. I am getting the error

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons
```

My component is,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { initialMessageAction, clickButtonAction } from './redux.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Message } from './messageComponent';

class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('component will mount');
    let data = this.props.initialMessageAction();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('comp Did Update')
    console.log(this.props.message)
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">        
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
        react-redux-data-flow
        </p> 
              <div>{this.props.message}</div>
             <div>{this.props? <div>hi ..<button onClick={ () => this.props.clickButtonAction() }>hide message</button></div>: ''}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


    const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProperty) => ({ 

    message:state.geod,   


  });   

   const mapDispatchToProps =  { 

     initialMessageAction,
    clickButtonAction

  } 

  export default connect(
                             mapStateToProps,
                             mapDispatchToProps

                    )(App);
```

Comment: Do you have mapStateToProps inside your component? Please show me your component code?

Comment: Why `geod` in `prevState` is object and in `nextState` is array?
Show your component.

Comment: @Andrew I included my component above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const initialState = {message: null};
 export const geod = (state = initialState, action) => {
      console.log('inside reducer');
        switch(action.type){
            case 'INITIAL_MESSAGE':
                return Object.assign({}, state, {message:'hello brozz..'});
            case 'CLICK_MESSAGE':
                return Object.assign({}, state, {message: ''}); 
            default:
                return state;
        }

     };
```

And in `stateMap` `{ message: state.geod.message }`.

As initial state You use an empty object and you see it in error.

Comment: But it shows `TypeError: Cannot read property 'geod' of undefined`

Comment: thanks for your help.Your answer and `{ message: state.geod.message}` solved my problem

Comment: Oh `{ message: state.geod.message }` without `this`

Comment: Why use `return Object.assign({}, state, {message:'hello brozz..'});`  instead of  `return [
                        ...state, {
                          message:'hello brozz..'
                        }
                      ]`

Comment: You can use your variant to, but keep that `state.geod` will be an array. And message you will get with `state.geod[0].message `